# Перевод секунд в удобный для чтения формат

Tags: время, javascript

Есть определенное число секунд продолжительности видео, надо перевести их в вид "час:мин:сек".

```
 var min = (3118 / 60) + ''
 var newN = min.slice(0,5)
 var left = newN.slice(0,newN.indexOf('.'))
 var right = newN.slice(newN.indexOf('.')+1)
 right = (right > 59) ? '59' : right
 var result = left +':'+ right
```

Есть ли более лучший код?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Например сделать функцию — http://jsfiddle.net/5DVMm/1/

```
var timeFormat = (function (){
    function num(val){
        val = Math.floor(val);
        return val < 10 ? '0' + val : val;
    }

    return function (ms/**number*/){
        var sec = ms / 1000
          , hours = sec / 3600  % 24
          , minutes = sec / 60 % 60
          , seconds = sec % 60
        ;

        return num(hours) + ":" + num(minutes) + ":" + num(seconds);
    };
})();

timeFormat(13325*1000); // 04:42:05
```

Ещё можно воспользоваться библиотекой [momentjs](http://momentjs.com/):

```
moment(13325*1000).format('hh:mm:ss'); // 04:42:05
```

Comment: Только ж `Math.floor` вместо `Math.round`, не? Иначе 31-ую секунду покажет неправильно.

Comment: Не, не покажут.

Comment: А минуту? Запустите сами свой же пример и подождите 31 секунду.

Comment: Да, что-то я не подумал о минутах, вы обсалютно правы, поправил пример.

Answer (score 4):

```
function pad2(num) {
    var s = num.toString();
    return (s.length < 2) "0" + s : s;
}

var m = Math.floor(seconds / 60);
var s = seconds % 60;
var h = Math.floor(m / 60);
m = m % 60;
var result = pad2(h) + ":" + pad2(m) + ":" + pad2(s);
```

Answer (score 4):

Как-то так можно, если время не больше одного дня, если больше (но не больше месяца), то `split` на `replace` можно заменить

```
var seconds=600
console.log(new Date(seconds*1000).toUTCString().split(/ /)[4]);
```

Comment: Зачетный способ.

Answer (score 1):

```js
long Tsec;
int Time[4] = 0;
...
Time[0] = TSec / 86400; //Day
Time[1] = (TSec % 86400) / 3600; //HH
Time[2] = (TSec % 3600) / 60; //MM
Time[3] = TSec % 60; //SS
```

Answer (score 0):

```
TimeInSeconds=61
TimeSrt=(new Date(TimeInSeconds * 1000).toISOString().substr(11, 12))
```

-->00.01.01:000

```
//or
TimeInSeconds=61
TimeSrt=(new Date(TimeInSeconds * 1000).toISOString().substr(11, 8))
```

-->00.01.01