# Как в таймере обратного отсчета разделить секунды на часы/минуты/секунды?

Tags: jquery

Есть функция - таймер обратного отсчета. Она считает от заданного количества секунд до нуля.

```
function countDown() {
    var seconds = 70997;
    var timer = setInterval(function() {
        if (seconds > 0) {
            seconds --;
            if (seconds < 10) {
                seconds = "0" + seconds;
            }
            $(".timer .seconds").text(seconds);
        } else {
            clearInterval(timer);
        }
    }, 1000);
}
```

seconds = 70997 - 19 часов / 43 минуты / 17 секунд.
Как в таймере разделить вывод на часы / секунды / минуты?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Перевод секунд в удобный для чтения формат](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/225570/%d0%9f%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b4-%d1%81%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%83%d0%bd%d0%b4-%d0%b2-%d1%83%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b9-%d0%b4%d0%bb%d1%8f-%d1%87%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d1%84%d0%be%d1%80%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%82)

Comment: Неточно она у вас считает. Нельзя так таймеры писать. Воспользуйтесь классом `Date`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Есть простейшее деление

```js
function countDown() {
    var seconds = 70997;
    var timer = setInterval(function() {
        if (seconds > 0) {
            seconds --;
            var h = seconds/3600 ^ 0,
                m = (seconds-h*3600)/60 ^ 0,
                s = seconds-h*3600-m*60,
                time = (h<10?"0"+h:h)+" ч. "+(m<10?"0"+m:m)+" мин. "+(s<10?"0"+s:s)+" сек.";
            $("body").text(time);
        } else {
            clearInterval(timer);
        }
    }, 1000);
}
$(function() {
  countDown()
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```